# How to check for existence and create a folder starting with dot in VBS?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have to check for existence of a folder starting with dot.
When I run this script, it returns False on `.FolderExists` (but that folder already exists!). Then, it return Err.Number 53 on `.CreateFolder` (yes, this folder already exists!).

How can I handle folders starting with a dot?

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strFolderTest
strFolderTest = "C:\project\node_modules\.bin"

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderTest) = False Then
    WScript.Echo("Folder does not exists: " & strFolderTest)
    On Error Resume Next
    objFSO.CreateFolder(strFolderTest)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 53 Then
            WScript.Echo("Ops, folder already exists!")
            Err.Clear
            WScript.quit(1)
        End If
    End If
    WScript.Echo("Folder created!")
Else
    WScript.Echo("Ok, folder already exists!")
End If
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: `FileSystemObject` does not have any problem dealing with a `.bin` named folder. The usual reason for the behaviour you expose (folder does not exist but creation fails) are: there is a file (not folder) with the same name or a rights problem.

Comment: I did a new test. It only occurs when the folder is on a network drive.

Comment: And this only occurs with ".bin" name. I've tested with .data and .env and this script works well.

Comment: Just because you can't *see* something on a network drive doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist. Windows can be configured to hide content in shares that the user has no access to. I just tested creation of a dot-folder on a network drive and it worked perfectly fine. Please double-check *on the server* that the folder really does not exist. Also, please update your question with an example that better resembles your actual code (since you're obviously not trying to create a local folder).